# Number of solutions to $\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma_0(a_k)=N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many solutions are there to
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma_0(a_k)=N$$
, where $a_k<K$ and $N$ are positive integers?

More precisely, I am looking for a closed form for $S(n,N)$, the number of solutions for a given $n,N$.

Note that I am using the standard notation that
$$\sigma_a(x)=\sum_{d|n}d^a.$$

Comment: Is $\sigma_0$ the sum-of-divisors function?

Comment: No, it's the number-of-divisors function.

Comment: Since you never tell us what $n$ is, I assume you want to use every possible partition of $p$ and then find some suitable $a_k$ to substitute into for every number on the partition? If I'm not clear, consider the partitions of $3$, $1+1+1$ and $2+1$. The $a_k$s are numbers such that $d(a_k)=1$ or $d(a_k)=2$, and that's why the bound is necessary (infinitude of primes...). I think this idea is a sketch of a possible final answer. Also, I think $p$ being prime or not represents no additional difficulties on the problem.

Comment: @IanMateus you are correct in your interpretation. I'm happy with individual examples, I just wondered whether it was possible to generalise.